# как дождаться полной прогрузки страницы selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как дождаться полной прогрузки сайта после нажатия на кнопку, selenium не дождавшись прогрузки пытается найти эти элементы и не находит
`

```
        email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='quick_email']")

        email.send_keys(login)


        passwords = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='quick_pass']")

        passwords = passwords[0]

        passwords.send_keys(password)

        LoginButton = driver.find_element_by_id("quick_login_button")


        LoginButton.click()
        
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="page_info_wrap"]/div[1]/h1').text
        friend = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="wide_column"]/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/div[1]').text
        subscriptions = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="profile_idols"]/a/div/span[2]').text`
```

пробовал уже и `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "html")))`

и  `element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.url_changes('ссылка которую вы ждете'))`

всё равно не ждёт и пытается найти, а элементы ещё не подгруженны

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26566799/13970074

Comment: я уже пробовал, он всё равно не дожидается

Comment: Попробуйте все методы, которые там есть. А ещё в связанных вопросах тоже